# woocommerce on wordpress pushing right bar below

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, widget

I have a WordPress site where I am using a purchasaed template and woocommerce for the shop. The problem is on the shop page the right bar gets pushed down. When I enquired about this issue from the developers of the template I was told to purchase shop beginner kit for the problem to fix.

That doesn't make sense to me, there must be a way to put the right bar properly to the right on the shop page when it is working fine on the other pages by editing either the PHP or CSS.

I tried editing the quick css, however, all it did was from the bar from left side to right side, however, it still stayed below.

Would appreciate any direction that someone can give as to which php to edit and how to go about it, my WordPress knowledge is at beginners level.

The page in questions would  be

http://needlestosaymore.com/product-category/house-warmers/

Answer (score 0):

one needs to edit archive-product.php page accordingly to make the changes which is found in the woocommerce plugin folder